# Using _.matches() and to filter Backbone models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to filter all Backbone models that have multiple key/value paris that are equal. For example, I want to match all/first model that has the ID of 123 and name is 'John'.

I realize there are other ways to do this, but would like to leverage the `matches()` method.

Is it possible to use Underscore's `matches()` method to create a function to pass to `filter` or `find` to find a Backbone model?

```
var search_fn = _.matches({id: 123, type: 'John'});
var should_be_active = _.find(master_model_array, search_fn);
```

Comment: I don't know why not; are you having a specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should certainly work, similar to what you have done but using "filter".

To reiterate:

```
// Sample data
var x = {name:"j", id: 1},
    y = {name: "j", id: 2},
    z = {name: "j", id: 1, more: "data"},
    match = _.matches({name: "j", id: 1});
var list = [x,y,z];

var result = _.filter(list, match);
```

This results in x and z as it matches the criteria. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsv/wkcj09oj/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Will this code work with Backbone models (as opposed to object literals x, y, and z)?

Comment: Also, your code also works using the `find` method, in addition to the `filter` method.